# Why can't the setLayout method be used with an ArrayList of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, layout-manager

I am quite new to swing and I had a question about layout managers. When I use setLayout() to put a layout manager in place for a single container I have no issues. Example:

```
JPanel oneContainer = new JPanel();
oneContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

This works fine.

What I want to do is set a certain layout manager for ever container in  an ArrayList. **Is there any way of doing this without cycling through each element with a loop.**

Example:

```
ArrayList<JPanel> multipleContainers = new ArrayList<>();
multipleContainers.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

(or something like that, you get the idea, I'm aware that the code provided is obviously erroneous, I'm also aware that to set a layout manager for a single ArrayList element I would just add .get(num) after the "multipleContainers") TIA

Comment: `Is there any way of doing this without cycling through each element with a loop.` - What is wrong with using a loop??? its two lines of code!!!

Comment: @camickr Lol I was just curious to see if there was a way of doing it :) ... I have nothing against using a loop.

Comment: And even if there were a way to do it, there's still gonna be a loop. It'll just be a loop you didn't have to write for yourself...

Comment: @KevinAnderson Let's just say I was asking on behalf of elegance.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry! You just have to suck it up and do it the hard way :)  Actually it's not so hard with a for-each loop:

```
for (JPanel p : multipleContainers)
    p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Or, as you've already surmised, there's the old-fashioned way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < multipleContainers.size(); ++i)
    multipleContainers.get(i).setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the type of multipleContainers is ArrayList, instead of JPanel. So setLayout() does not work here.

If you want to setLayout() works, you need to iterate the ArrayList to get panels.

Comment: I'm aware of this, I mentioned this up above.